# How can I make two servers (e.g. localhost:6000 and localhost:7000) communicate with each other using multiprocessing.connection in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipc, python-multiprocessing

An example on [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) shows how to connect a server and a client.

Server:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

address = ('localhost', 6000)

with Listener(address, authkey=b'secret password') as listener:
    with listener.accept() as conn:
        print('connection accepted from', listener.last_accepted)
        conn.send([2.25, None, 'junk', float])
```

Client:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client

address = ('localhost', 6000)

with Client(address, authkey=b'secret password') as conn:
    print(conn.recv())
```

I want to make one little change: instead of a server and a client, I want to have two servers at localhost:6000 and localhost:7000. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: If you want a more symmetrical connection between processes, you should probably use `multiprocessing.Pipe()` instead of `.connection`.

Comment: @jasonharper What is a symmetrical connection? I'm new to Python.

Comment: This is very low-level for a beginner. Why not use a regular `socket` connection, or even HTTP or gRPC servers?